# after table and apply , how can i assign it

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(Equip = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 Notif = c(1,1,1,5,5,3,3,3,3,4),
                 Component = c("1","1","1","2","2","1","2","2","2","3"))
```

where the `Notif` column was categorized into the `Component` column (because it might not be relevant, I won't show how I went about creating that column.)

Now I have a table that maps `Notif` values to a corresponding category:

```
 example <- 1 "repair" ; 3 "service" ; 4 "other" ; 5 "service"
```

How can I create and add a `Category` vector to my data.frame?

Comment: please tag you question to related technologies.

Comment: i really do not know which would be related, i tag it to r because i have to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a named vector for mapping `Notif` to `Category`:

```
categories <- c(`1` = "repair", `3` = "service", `4` = "other",  `5` = "service")
```

Then you can do:

```
df$Category <- categories[as.character(df$Notif)]
```

or equivalently

```
df <- transform(df, Category = categories[as.character(Notif)])
```

In both cases, the output is:

```
df
#    Equip Notif Component Category
# 1      1     1         1   repair
# 2      1     1         1   repair
# 3      1     1         1   repair
# 4      1     5         2  service
# 5      1     5         2  service
# 6      2     3         1  service
# 7      2     3         2  service
# 8      2     3         2  service
# 9      2     3         2  service
# 10     2     4         3    other
```

---

Another approach is by merging data.frames, like a database join:

```
categories <- data.frame(Notif = c(1, 3, 4, 5),
                         Category = c("repair", "service", "other", "service"))

merge(df, categories, by = "Notif", all.x = TRUE)
#    Notif Equip Component Category
# 1      1     1         1   repair
# 2      1     1         1   repair
# 3      1     1         1   repair
# 4      3     2         1  service
# 5      3     2         2  service
# 6      3     2         2  service
# 7      3     2         2  service
# 8      4     2         3    other
# 9      5     1         2  service
# 10     5     1         2  service
```

Note that the output is reordered by `Notif` which may or may not be a problem to you. This approach becomes particularly useful when `Notif` maps to more than one variables like `Category`.